# Two NavigationView in an Activity and Opening and Closing them with two seperate buttons in AppBarLayout

Tags: android, layout

I have an activity in which I have to NavigationView. One in the left side and the other on the right side. Both NavigationViews appear in the activity and works fine when swiped accordingly from left to right and right to left. I have two buttons in the AppBarLayout. I need to control these NavigationView with these buttons. (for eg, when I click button1 NavigationView1 should appear and when clicked on button2 NavigationView2 should appear)

This is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_main_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/br_blue_2"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_normal"
            android:background="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/notification_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_notification" />
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure which part(s) you're asking about, exactly. Are you asking how to put those buttons in your layout? Or how to set `OnClickListener`s on them? Or how to open/close the drawers from those listeners?

Comment: @MikeM. I have the buttons in the layout. I need to open/close these drawers with the buttons

Comment: `DrawerLayout` has the `openDrawer()` and `closeDrawer()` methods. Both of those have two overloads, so you can pass them either the `NavigationView`s directly, or a gravity value, like `GravityCompat.START`.

Answer (score -1):

Your `NavigationView`s have the same `@id`. You should give them different `@id`s and toggle them with different buttons.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35956854/2629065) for how to include an ExpandableListView on your NaviagtionView.

Comment: one is " android:id="@+id/notification_menu"  and other is "android:id="@+id/navigation_menu". I dont get your point. Both these are different. Right ?